# create a finder function with BeautifoulSoup

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scope

I have a `def` for web-scraping but when I put an attribute in a variable, (list) `beautifulsoup` doesn't resolve it, if i execute it returns `none` but if I put it by hand it works.

```
# llibreria x fer peticions html
import requests
#importem el Soup per fer busquedes al web
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#funcio x buscar a la web i fer codi reutilizable n
def finder(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url[0], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    result = soup.find(url[1])
    price = soup.find(url[2])
    price = price.replace("€","")
    price = price.replace(".","")
    price = int(price)
    print("__________ House Finded _________")
    print(result.text)
    print(price)
    print("________________________________")
    
    
habitaclia =[ "https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-casa_pareada-en_venta_en_llanca_el_colomer_la_bateria_la_coma-llansa-i16454000001818.htm?hab=3&ordenar=precio_mas_bajo&st=3,6,8,10,12,15&f=parking&geo=p&from=list&lo=55", "h1", "'span', {'itemprop':'price'"]
finder(habitaclia)
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that your string `"'span', {'itemprop':'price'"` is used as one `argument`, in this case as the tag name.

This is caused while `BeautifulSoup` is not parsing your string in the way you expect, it is not able two know that the string should represent two arguments separated by comma. String is is also missing a `}`

If you really wanna work that way try to change your strategy and use more structured information e.g. a `dict`:

```
habitaclia ={'url':'https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-casa_pareada-en_venta_en_llanca_el_colomer_la_bateria_la_coma-llansa-i16454000001818.htm?hab=3&ordenar=precio_mas_bajo&st=3,6,8,10,12,15&f=parking&geo=p&from=list&lo=55', 
             'tag_one':'h1', 
             'tag_two': 'span',
             'filter_two': {'itemprop':'price'}
            }
```

and use it in your script like this:

```
price = soup.find(config.get('tag_two'),config.get('filter_two')).text
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def finder(config):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(config.get('url'), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    result = soup.find(config.get('tag_one'))
    price = soup.find(config.get('tag_two'),config.get('filter_two')).text
    price = price.replace("€","")
    price = price.replace(".","")
    price = int(price)
    print("__________ House Finded _________")
    print(result.text)
    print(price)
    print("________________________________")


habitaclia ={'url':'https://www.habitaclia.com/comprar-casa_pareada-en_venta_en_llanca_el_colomer_la_bateria_la_coma-llansa-i16454000001818.htm?hab=3&ordenar=precio_mas_bajo&st=3,6,8,10,12,15&f=parking&geo=p&from=list&lo=55', 
             'tag_one':'h1', 
             'tag_two': 'span',
             'filter_two': {'itemprop':'price'}
            }

finder(habitaclia)
```

###### Result

```
__________ House Finded _________
Casa pareada  en venta en El Colomer - La Bateria - La Coma Llançà
248000
________________________________
```